# С помощью vba(ворд) реализовать программу для решения квадратичного уравнения, записанного на листе документа в виде a*x2+b*x+c=d

Tags: vba, ms-word

Реализовать программу для решения квадратичного уравнения, записанного на листе документа в виде a*x2+b*x+c=d
Вывод результата – строкой после уравнения на активном листе документа:
Шрифт Arial
Размер 16 pt.
Начертание: курсив.
Тут у меня даже идей нет, как решать уравнение записанное на листе документа в ворде.

Comment: Вероятно, нужно разобрать **строку**, выделив и неё коэффициенты

Comment: уравнение принято называть квадратным, а не квадратичным

Comment: Я понимаю, что квадратным, а не квадратичным, условие было так написано просто(да и мы программисты, а не учители русского языка).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub f()
    Dim regex As Object, res As Object, myRange As Range
    
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "-?(\d+)\*x2[+-](\d+)\*x[+-](\d+)=-?(\d+)"
        Set res = regex.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content)
    End With
    
    If res.Count > 0 Then
        a = Val(res(0).SubMatches(0))
        b = Val(res(0).SubMatches(1))
        c = Val(res(0).SubMatches(2))
        d = Val(res(0).SubMatches(3))
        c = c - d
        discr = b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c
        If discr < 0 Then
            out = "Корней нет"
        Else
            k1 = (-b + Sqr(discr)) / (2 * a)
            k2 = (-b - Sqr(discr)) / (2 * a)
            out = "Корни: 1) " & k1 & ", 2) " & k2
        End If
        
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
        myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=res(0)
        myRange.InsertAfter vbCrLf & out
        With myRange.Paragraphs(2).Range.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 16
            .Italic = True
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Полином 2-й степени не найден"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте шаблон в Excel и будет вам счастье. И вообще все дела связанные с расчетами и перемеными делайте в экселе. В пять раз меньше кода, потраченного времени и ошибок..

Comment: Я прекрасно понимаю, что это можно сделать в Excel, но нужно обязательно сделать ворде. Таково условие задания.